# Find 'x' rows where the sum of 'tokens' -column is as close to 'n' as possible

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

```
x = 100
Y = 1000
W = 50 

Table M = sports
Column T = wins
Column L = loses
```

I want to be able to select x records from table M where the sum of column T is equal to Y

for example find 100 teams that have a combined 1000 wins in total or as close as possible. I would like to also add some where clauses in addition;

```
select x records
from table M
where the sum of column T is equal to Y and loses is less than W
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL is not suitable for this type of task.  This is an optimization task that requires either an iterative optimization algorithm or perhaps matrix arithmetic.

Comment: Note that this is also in the class of NP complete problems and requires exponentially more computational effort as the number of tokens increases.

Comment: Thanks guys, I managed to achieve a satisfactory solution for now. It's a bit of a mess but it will work until/if the site becomes heavily used, if we make it that far then there will be enough dosh to go back to the drawing board with some greater minds.